# Goal "for" or Goal "of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> The goal **for** these negotiations is to reach a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that would ensure Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful.

while we have a noun phrase "the goal" connected to another noun phrase "these negotiations", why isn't *of* used instead of *for*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"of" and "for" are largely synonymous in this context. If you look at the definitions for "[of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of)" and "[for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for)" you'll see a massive amount of overlapping. Either word is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to think about it is this: "of" can be equated to "comes from" and "for" can be equated to "goes towards" (or "purpose.") These definitions are found in every dictionary I've checked.

A goal **"of"** the negotiations is a goal that was derived **from** the negotiations.

A goal **"for"** the negotiations is a goal that was meant to be applied **to** the negotiations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the distinction you are drawing for the "of" case is wrong. "Of" can refer to both the objective and subjective genitives, so it can be a goal arising from the negotiation or a goal that sets the purpose of the negotiations

Comment: Prepositions are hugely polysemous. I don't think any decent dictionary would not include the sense 'associated with' (AHD sense 9) for 'of'. Which covers all sorts of relationships (causal, resultative, showing ownership, incidental...) between say 'goal' and 'these negotiations'. I think that here, the connotation for the 'for' version is 'the goal for the negotiators', ie a less impersonal flavouring, but these things are very open to different interpretations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It makes me a bit surprised. since it is the text of a well-known deal between Iran and the 6 world powers, it should be as clear as possible, so that different senses can not be understood from the same sentence or phrase. Although here the use of "for" does not make a big difference, it looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: @Juya I'd use 'of' here, and Google hits for "goal of these negotiations" certainly outnumber those for "goal for these negotiations". And many of the latter seem to be for your actual quote. However, both are used, with very slight difference in meaning. Regarding your desire to ensure that 'different senses can not be understood from the same sentence or phrase', I think you're on a loser. As a friend of mine has said, 'All words are infinitely polysemous,' and as someone else said, 'A man hears what he wants to hear, and disregards the rest.' But yes, we should aim for precision.